# How to convert multidimensional array into a 2 dimensional array?

Tags: arrays, ruby

Having the following nested array

```
[[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4], [0, 5]], [[1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2],   [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5]], [[2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [2, 4], [2, 5]], [[3, 0], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3], [3, 4], [3, 5]], [[4, 0], [4, 1], [4, 2], [4, 3], [4, 4], [4, 5]], [[5, 0], [5, 1], [5, 2], [5, 3], [5, 4], [5, 5]]]
```

I'd like to remove subarray containers until it becomes a 2 dimensional array like:

```
[[0,0], [5,1], [5,4]...]
```

.flatten removes everything and I need to keep the groups of 2 within subarrays.

Comment: If `a` is your array you say that you want to produce the array `[[0,0], a[5][1], a[5][4]...]`. What is the rule for constructing that array?

Comment: using the matrix class

Comment: You selected an answer that generates an array beginning `[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2]...`, but you said it should be `[[0,0], [5,1], [5,4]...]`. Please explain.

Comment: The answer below has been marked as correct.  The code I typed was only meant to be a brief example of what I needed.

Comment: The downvote was mine. What you need is a better example, say: "given the 2-element array `arr = [[ [0,0], [0,1]], [[0,2], [0,3]]]` how can I produce the 4-element array `[[0,0], [0,1], [0,2], [0,3]]`".  Note three things: 1) the example is complete (no "..."); 2) the example is no larger than necessary; and 3) I have assigned a variable (`arr`) to the input object, so readers can use that variable in their answers and comments without having to define it (not necessary for outputs).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

also, next time you can try to read [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-flatten) :)

```
a = [[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4], [0, 5]], [[1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2],   [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5]], [[2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [2, 4], [2, 5]], [[3, 0], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3], [3, 4], [3, 5]], [[4, 0], [4, 1], [4, 2], [4, 3], [4, 4], [4, 5]], [[5, 0], [5, 1], [5, 2], [5, 3], [5, 4], [5, 5]]]

a.flatten(1)
>[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4], [0, 5], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [2, 4], [2, 5], [3, 0], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3], [3, 4], [3, 5], [4, 0], [4, 1], [4, 2], [4, 3], [4, 4], [4, 5], [5, 0], [5, 1], [5, 2], [5, 3], [5, 4], [5, 5]]
```